# Class object as List's type

Tags: java

I have class `Animal` and two subclasses `Tiger` and `Eagle`. Both of subclasses have `hunt` method which is pretty much the same. The only difference between them is type of *Victims*. Method hunt is using generic class `Field<T>` for seekeing victims. It looks like this:

**Tiger**

```
void hunt(){
  Field<Cattle> field = new Field<Cattle>();
  List<Cattle> list = field.getObjects();
  ...
```

**Eagle**

```
void hunt(){
  Field<Rabbit> field = new Field<Rabbit>();
  List<Rabbit> list = field.getObjects();
  ...
```

Is there any way to perform something like that?

```
void hunt(Object type){
  Field<type> field = new Field<type>();
  List<type> list = field.getObjects();
```

I know that I can get list full of `Object` type and use `instanceof` later, but here we come to second question:

Is it possible to call `if( object instanceof instanceOfSomeClass)`?

Comment: So you want to move `hunt()` method to super class?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention about that.

Comment: I guess that would not be possible. One option was to use generic method, but since there is neither any parameter for that method, nor any return type, type parameter would not be inferred. And it would make more sense to have that method in subclasses only, since they are really operating on different data.

Comment: I don't understand how `List<Cattle> = field.getObjects()` is a valid assignment, isn't this a variable declaration? What type does `field.getObjects()` return?

Comment: I've missed name of variable... my bad.

Comment: You missed it in the Tiger and Eagle classes also. Anyway, can't you create a superclass for `Rabbit` and `Cattle` and use this as the argument for `hunt`? If you specify a bit better what you want to achieve at the end it will be easier for us to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics to achieve what you want:

```
public class AnimalsGenerics<E> {
    public void Hunt(E prey){
       ...
    }
}
```

and implement your animals specifying the prey:

```
public class Tiger extends AnimalsGenerics<Buffalo> {
}
```

But my personal implementation would be using interfaces to specify what does the animal do, for example: what happens if the animal is not a hunter, for example an herbivorous, would you need to implement your animal class again? follow the principle of leaving the implementation to the interfaces and not the heritance would help you to have a cleaner code, my dessign would be:

To design the behaviour:

```
public interface CollectFoodBehaviour<E> {
    void collectFood(E prey);
}
```

Class animal would be:

```
public class Animal<E> {

    CollectFoodBehaviour<E> collectFoodBehaviour;

    public  void goToGetFood(E food){
        collectFoodBehaviour.collectFood(food);
    }
}
```

Implementing the hunting behaviour:

```
  public class HuntAnimalsBehaviour<E> implements CollectFoodBehaviour<E> {
        @Override
        public void collectFood(E prey) {
            //implemenet the generic hunting process
        }
    }
```

and an animal instance as an example:

```
public class Dog extends Animal<Rabbit> {

    public Dog(){
        this.collectFoodBehaviour = new HuntAnimalsBehaviour<Rabbit>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to call if( object instanceof instanceOfSomeClass)?

No, **instanceof** tests if an object is an instance of a class, not an instance of an instance (as if the left side is a non-static reference and the right side is static reference); You can, however, not declare your instance

```
// JButton b = new JButton();
// if (b instanceof Component) can be replced with
if (JButton.class.newInstance() instanceof Component)
// or
if (new JButton() instanceof Component)
```

if for some odd reason you find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can use a generic method using following code:

If you pass the object class, not the instance, you can construct a `Field` instance using the `Class` passed as parameter.

```
public class MyAnimal {
    public <T> void hunt(Class<T> type) {
        Field<T> field = new Field<>();
        List<T> list = field.getObjects();

        if (type == Cattle.class) {
            System.out.println("Type is a Cattle");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Type is not a Cattle, is a " + type.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyAnimal().hunt(Cattle.class);
        new MyAnimal().hunt(new Cattle().getClass());
    }
}
```

About your second question, if you have the Class type, you can ask with a simple: `type == MyClass.class`.